# Uninstalling and RE-Installing python-dateutil

Tags: jupyter, python-dateutil

I was getting an error while accessing my jupyter notebook which was a syntax error in dateutil module so I uninstalled it using pip uninstall pyhton-dateutil and then while installing it again using pip install python-dateutil I got this message
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.5)

then for removing it completely I tried rm -rf ./miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil

someone please suggest me what to do as my jupyter notebook is not working as it need dateutil for working

Answer (score 0):

the best way to resolve this issue use the **conda commands**

open anaconda prompt (go to start and search anaconda prompt)

now use the following two commands 
1) First execute this command  `conda uninstall -c anaconda dateutil` 
2)  `conda install -c anaconda dateutil`

This will work for you. 
if not work please let me know.

Comment: I went to the base directory of storage and used rm -rf their

Comment: And reinstalled using pip again but thanks for the help though I have one problem I installed miniconda but still when I use any conda command it shows conda not found so if you can help with this that will be helpful Thanks again

Comment: it is always better to use `conda` command to install uninstall libraries, packages when you are using conda products such as jupyterNootebook, spyder

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion it will be helpful if you can help with the comment just above